# Xpath - how do I return the numerical value from a span class only if it contains certain text?

Tags: xpath

Here's my code:

```
<span class="price-val_90931611 odd-val ib right">
```

How do I return only "90931611" and I only want it returned though if the span class contains "price-val".

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit crooky, but still

```
translate(substring-after(//*[contains(@class,'price-val')]/@class,'price-val_'),' odd-val ib right','')
```

**UPD:**

```
substring(substring-after(//*[contains(@class,'price-val')]/@class,'price-val_'), 1, 8)
```

in case it is known that the number consists of 8 digits.

Comment: I used the first one and it worked perfectly, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will be a space after the target string (i.e. it's not the only class name or the last class name in the value), then the following will work:

```
substring-before(
    substring-after(//span[contains(@class, 'price-val')]/@class, 'price-val_'), 
    ' ')
```

In the case where it *is* the last (or the only) class name, then all you need is this:

```
substring-after(//span[contains(@class, 'price-val')]/@class, 'price-val_')
```

If you're not sure, or you want to be flexible (always a good idea), the following will work in any case:

```
substring-before(
    substring-after(concat(' ', 
                           //span[contains(@class, 'price-val')]/@class, 
                           ' '), 
                    'price-val_'), 
    ' ')
```

It's obviously uglier, but by using `concat` to surround the target class with spaces, we are able to guarantee that the outer functions grab the value we're looking for in each of the possible cases.